# Не меняется иконка при нажатии на кнопку меню

Tags: javascript, html, css

При нажатии на меню должна меняться иконка, но этого не происходит, что здесь не так?

```js
$('.menu-icon').click(function() {
  $('.men').slideToggle(500);

  if ($('.menu-icon').html() == '<i class="fas fa-bars"></i>') {
    $(this).html('<i class="fas fa-times"></i>')
  } else {
    $(this).html('<i class="fas fa-bars"></i>')
  }
})
```

```css
.logo-bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-icon {
  display: block;
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .men {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xl-3 logo-bar">
  <img src="assets/img/logo.png" class="logo">
  <button class="menu-icon"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>
</div>

<div class="col-xl-5 ml-auto align-self-center men">
  <nav>
    <ul class="menu d-flex justify-content-end">
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#home" data-target="anchor">Home</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#about" data-target="anchor">About</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#news" data-target="anchor">News</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#testimonials" data-target="anchor">Testimonials</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#contact" data-target="anchor">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправим ошибку и изменим "замену" иконки.

```js
let buttonIcon = $('.menu-icon i'),
    buttonIcon_bars = 'fa-bars',
    buttonIcon_times = 'fa-times';

$('.menu-icon').click(function() {
  $('.men').slideToggle(500);
  
  if(buttonIcon.hasClass(buttonIcon_bars)) {
    buttonIcon.removeClass(buttonIcon_bars).addClass(buttonIcon_times);
  } else {
      buttonIcon.removeClass(buttonIcon_times).addClass(buttonIcon_bars);
  }
})
```

```css
.logo-bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-icon {
  display: block;
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .men {
    display: none;
  }
}

.menu-icon {
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-xl-3 logo-bar">
  <img src="assets/img/logo.png" class="logo">
  <button class="menu-icon">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </button>
</div>

<div class="col-xl-5 ml-auto align-self-center men">
  <nav>
    <ul class="menu d-flex justify-content-end">
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#home" data-target="anchor">Home</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#about" data-target="anchor">About</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#news" data-target="anchor">News</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#testimonials" data-target="anchor">Testimonials</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#contact" data-target="anchor">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

В приведённом вами коде нет класса `.men`

```js
$('.menu-icon').click(function() {
  $('.logo').attr('src', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Star_icon-72a7cf.svg');
})
```

```css
.menu-icon {
  display: block;
  color: white;
}
.logo-bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xl-3 logo-bar">
  
  <button class="menu-icon"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/a/a3/FSlogo.png" class="logo"></button>
</div>
```